# Why i add new button and list thing,it won't do request 1 and 2?

Tags: javascript

request1:click on the list item, it toggles the .done  class on and off.

request2:Add buttons next to each list item to delete the item when clicked the button

request3:adding a new list item, it automatically adds the delete button next to it. Also meet the request 1 and 2

The question i want to ask is that I have already done request 1 and 2,as title said:Why i add new button and list item,it won't do request 1 and 2

first code is js,second code is css,third code is html.
request1 needs to use css which is called .done
in my js:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var span= document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var DeleteButton=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
/*Delete button */
[...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', () =>
    el.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(el.parentNode)));

/*toggle .done property*/
for(var i=0; i<span.length; i++){
   span[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}
function liClick(){
 this.classList.toggle("done");
}  


function inputLength() {
 return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");
    var deletebutton = document.createElement("button")
    var spanitem = document.createElement("span")
 spanitem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    deletebutton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
 ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(spanitem)
    li.appendChild(deletebutton);
 input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
 if (inputLength() > 0) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
 if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul id="Delete">
        <li class="bold red" random="23">
            <span>Notebook</span>
            <button >Delete</button>
        </li>
        
  <li>
            <span>Jello</span>
            <button >Delete</button>
        </li>
        
  <li>
      <span>Spinach</span>
            <button >Delete</button>
        </li>
        
  <li>
            <span>Rice</span>
            <button >Delete</button>
        </li>
        
  <li>
       <span>Birthday Cake</span>
       <button >Delete</button>
    
        </li>
        
  <li>
        <span>Candles</span>
        <button>Delete</button>
        </li>
        
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The updated JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.getElementById("Delete");
var span= document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var DeleteButton=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
/*Delete button */
[...document.querySelectorAll('.del')].forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', () =>
    el.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(el.parentNode)));

/*toggle .done property*/
for(var i=0; i<span.length; i++){
   span[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}
function liClick(){
 this.classList.toggle("done");
}  


function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        li.classList.toggle("done");
    })
    var deletebutton = document.createElement("button")
    var spanitem = document.createElement("span")
    spanitem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    deletebutton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    deletebutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        ul.removeChild(li);
    });
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(spanitem)
    li.appendChild(deletebutton);
    input.value = "";

}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

And add "del" class to all your button elements